# Modify Mixed-Content HTMLs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mixed-content

At first I didn't have any SSL certificate in my site because hosting providers didn't allow it.

So, I've transferred my domain to CloudFlare & got a SSL certificate for my site.

For a SSL certificate the contents in the site should be like `<img src="**https**://www.example.com/image.png` (not `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png">`), otherwise it will show an issue about Mixed-Content..

So, by following the rules, I did the same thing.. But at the bottom some third-party ads were placed owned by hosting providers which contains `http://` connection. So as a result I got an untrusted certificate error in the Browsers.

Hosting providers doesn't allow to edit or remove those items by paying or something else.

But CloudFlare already has a system to change all `<script src="http://www.example.com/script.js"></script>` into `<script src="https://www.example.com/script.js"></script>` automatically. But my problem is, it can't change `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png">` into `<img src="https://www.example.com/image.png">`.

Is it possible to modify `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png">` into `<img src="https://www.example.com/image.png">` using JavaScript?? And will it be resolved if I use JavaScript??

Comment: Did you try setting the `src` and seeing what happens?

Comment: `Is it possible` - yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using String.replace on the document HTML.

Edit: Upon more research, you might want to try using:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

Instead of a JavaScript solution

```js
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace("http://", "https://");
console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<img src="http://somethingsomething">
```

Comment: It isn't inside <body> tags.. it is outside <html> tags.. I mean <!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>{Here Ads}.. what should I do right now?

Comment: @user8427031 Try using `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: YES! YES! YES! YES! Unfortunately javascript wasn't working.. but meta tag works like a charm!